# Regenerate sources when AdditionalFiles content changed in IncrementalSourceGenerator

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, sourcegenerators

I would like to know is it possible somehow to regenerate sources in IncrementalSourceGenerator when content of AdditionalFiles changed?

I need to regenerate sources in realtime when user will change additional files, but for now I can do this only when I build or re-build project.

I know that MAUI is uodated to IncrementalSourceGenerator and I would like to know how they subscribed to AdditionalFiles changes in generator.
Or does this actually possible?

Comment: Does the [first example in the docs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/incremental-generators.md#simple-example) not answer this?

Comment: @canton7 I tried this code in Visual Studio 2022 and in Rider and in both cases I didnt receive correct output. In any way I need to rebuild solution to generate sources.